# How to fix this AttributeError inside my for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, pycharm

I'm a programming beginner and this is my first question, so please forgive me if I made any mistakes, but here is my problem:

I was tasked to do a "sort of" Employee management system in Python as a "OOP" homework from school. The instructions are:

1.It has to have an add employee feature which takes user input of the name, the position, the department and finally the rate of the employee.

2.The second option requires to compute the hourly, which is basically multiplying rate * hourly

3.The third option requires you to print all of your employees that you entered (everything is looped so there can be multiple employees not just one.)

4.And finally exit which just terminates the console.

Everything seems to be running fine until I ran into an "AttributeError" on the 3rd option. And I can't seem to figure it out

The error is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/activities/OOP.py", line 58, in 
    print(employees.index(x), x.n, x.d, x.p, x.r)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'n'

I've tried this loop but as I've said it gives the same error:

elif ans == 3:

```
    for x in employees:
        print(employees.index(x), x.n, x.d, x.p, x.r)
        continue
```

The code is fairly short and simple, but all I'm having trouble with is option number 3.

```
employees = []
running = True
```

class Employees:

```
def __init__(self, n, d, p, r):
    self.n = n
    self.d = d
    self.p = p
    self.r = r

def compute(self, h):
    return h * self.r


while running:
    print("Choose your option: ")
    print("[1] Add new employee")
    print("[2] Enter hourly of employee")
    print("[3] Show employee information")
    print("[4] Exit")

print("Enter option: ", end="")
ans = int(input())

if ans == 1:
    print("Enter employee name: ", end="")
    n = input()
    employees.append(n)
    print("Enter department: ", end="")
    d = input()
    employees.append(d)
    print("Enter position: ", end="")
    p = input()
    employees.append(p)
    print("Enter rate: ", end="")
    r = int(input())
    employees.append(r)

    employees.append(Employees(n, d, p, r))

    continue

elif ans == 2:
    e1 = Employees(n, d, p, r)
    print("Enter the index of the employee")

    y = int(input())
    print(employees[y] + " is selected")
    print("Enter the hourly of employee: ")
    z = int(input())
    print(e1.compute(r))

elif ans == 3: #Option 3

    for x in employees: #This loop seems to be the problem
        print(employees.index(x), x.n, x.d, x.p, x.r)
        continue

elif ans == 4:
    running = False

else:
    print("Invalid input, please try again: ")
    continue
break
```

The result I was expecting was something like:

```
Name: Greg
Department: IT
Position: Technician
Rate: 450

Name: Isaac
Department: HR
Position: Manager
Rate: 700
```

But I'm getting this error instead:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/activities/OOP.py", line 59, in 
    print(employees.index(x), x.n, x.d, x.p, x.r)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'n'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part of your code you are appending the strings to the employees list

```
if ans == 1:
print("Enter employee name: ", end="")
n = input()
employees.append(n)
print("Enter department: ", end="")
d = input()
employees.append(d)
print("Enter position: ", end="")
p = input()
employees.append(p)
print("Enter rate: ", end="")
r = int(input())
employees.append(r)

employees.append(Employees(n, d, p, r))

continue
```

see employees.append(n) which is probably a name (string)

so when you call

```
for x in employees:
```

you try to do x.n but the string appended has no attribute "n"

Comment: No, what I mean is `for x in employees` will iterate over each element in the employees list, and it looks like the first element in the list is a string. Strings do not have an attribute named "n" so in your loop, when you call `x.n` inside the print statement it raises the AttributeError you see.

Comment: I'd say try removing the `employees.append()` calls except the one that says `employees.append(Employees(n, d, p, r))`

Comment: Oh thank you i understand that now and now it is working fine, but now I am getting another error on option number 2.

Comment: Enter the index of the employee
0
<__main__.Employees object at 0x000001805880EBC8>  is selected
Enter the hourly of employee: 
2. It doesnt seem to know what index im choosing because it throws an unidentified object(?)

Comment: could you comment the exact error message? It might be because you're doing `e1.compute(r)` instead of `employees[y].compute(r)`

Comment: Enter the index of the employee: 0
<__main__.Employees object at 0x000001E3A7B6EB88>  is selected

Comment: It is not exactly an error it just does not display the name, of the index that i am selecting. And it does not compute accurately either.

Comment: `<__main__.Employees object at 0x000001E3A7B6EB88>` is what you would expect actually, if you want the object's name you'd wanna call `employees[y].n`

Also noticed that in the option 2 block, you're referencing variables `n, d, p, r` which I think are out of the block's scope

Comment: Oooh, thank you, Im really learning alot, I manage to solve the computation problem by using employees[y].r * z

Comment: But I have one last question. Why does my loop terminate even with the continue keyword.

Comment: 'elif ans == 3:

        for x in employees:
            print("\n Name:", x.n, "\n Department:", x.d, "\n Position:", x.p, "\n Rate:", x.r)

            continue'

Comment: the continue statement is inside the for loop's block so it continues the for loop, not the while True loop. unindent it

Comment: Oh, yes, It was just a silly indent error. Thank you for helping this beginner out